# Exclude keys from record

Tags: typescript, record, mapped-types, keyof

I have the following generic mapped type:

```
export type KeyRules<Input> = {
  [K in keyof Input]?: Rule<Input[K], Input>};
```

I want to define another that looks something like:

```
export type ExtendedRules<Input> = Omit<
  Record<string, Rule<Input, Input>>,
  keyof Input
>;
```

or

```
export type ExtendedRules<Input> = {
  [K in Exclude<string, keyof Input>]?: Rule<Input, Input>
};
```

or

```
export type ExtendedRules<Input> = Record<
  Exclude<string, keyof Input>,
  Rule<Input, Input>
>;
```

And then I would define a third type:

```
export type Rules = KeyRules & ExtendedRules;
```

However I can't seem to exclude the keys of Input. `ExtendedRules<Input>` is always equivalent to `Record<string, Rule<Input, Input>`.

I've also tried a conditional type:

```
export type Rules<Input> = {
  [k: string]: k extends keyof Input ? Rule<Input[typeof k], Input> : Rule<Input, Input>
}
```

This also did not work

Is it actually possible to have a sort of negated mapped object type?

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not work for your use case, but you can declare the value types for the keys you want to omit as `never` instead of trying to delete the keys entirely.  This often has the same effect.

Example:

```
type bannedKeys = "a" | "b" | "c"

type myType = {
    [key: string]: string;
} & {
    [key in bannedKeys]: never;
}

declare const obj: myType;

const test1 = obj["a"]; // test1 has type 'never'
const test2 = obj["d"]; // test2 has type 'string'
```